# Redirect Parse Error in PHP

Tags: php

Can I redirect to another page when there is any parse error in PHP code . By setting error handler i can only redirect warning errors, notice errors but not parse errors . Please help me out.
my code is:-

```
<?php
    set_error_handler("error_handle");
    function getIp(){
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
    function error_handle($errno,$error_message,$error_file,$error_line,$error_context){
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        include 'dbconnection.php';
        echo $hash1=$_SESSION['Hash1'];
        echo $hash3=$_SESSION['Hash3'];
        $ip=getIp();

        header('Location:error.php');
    }

    echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: Parse errors are not catchable. You can't trap them and handle them...yet. Look out for PHP 7

Answer (score 3):

PHP will not render code that has a parse error. Parse errors are very easy to catch by using the -l (lowercase L) option with PHP on the command-line:

```
$ php -l myfile.php
```

This will not run the code, but will simply report any parse errors.

EDIT: I do not recommend using code to detect parse errors, but just to prove Hobo wrong when he says "this can't be done", the following function (while not recommended) will redirect if a parse error is detected in an included file. Note that this solution requires that php-cli be installed on the server:

```
/**
 * @param string $filename
 * @return NULL
 */
function safeInclude($filename)
{

    exec('php -l ' . $filename, $output, $parse_error);
    if (!$parse_error)
    {
        include($filename);
    }
    else
    {
        // include another file or redirect using header()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not catching the errors. That's just using the PHP interpreter as a linter. The OP wants to be able to catch syntax errors and handle them in the code. This can't be done in current versions but PHP7 offers some functionality in this area.

Comment: Thanks tony for the solution but i want to store this error in the database . is there any solution of it

Comment: Nimish, The $ouptut array will have the error in it. You can store the contents of $output[0] to the database before redirecting.